# Data for the maximum date for an employee

Tags: obiee

I need to to get the value on the maximum date for a particular employee.

Eg: I select 30/06/2017 as the date. But for the employee the Score is 0 on 30/06/2017. But on 28/06/2017 he has a value of 94. So, I need to show this value in my report.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Wait. Are you wanting to show the maximum date, but with the value 94 (or whatever the max value for that employee is)?

Comment: The maximum date which has got value for a particular employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution Write filters as TOPN(Date, 1 by Employee) is equal to/is in 1, Score not in (NULL, 0) and Date is prompted. This works.